# PostgreSQL. Stored function or query improvements

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql

I'm using **PostgreSQL** and have an **employee** table:

```
employeeid | FirstName | LastName | Department | Position
    1      | Aaaa      |          |            |
    2      | Bbbb      |          |            |
    3      |           |          |            |
    .      |           |          |            |
```

**Reports** table:

```
employeeid |        enter        |        exit
     1     | 2020-11-08 09:02:21 | 2020-11-08 18:12:01
     .     |         ...         |
```

Now, I'm querying for missed employees on a certain date something like that function:

```
for i in select employeeid from employee
loop
    if select not exists(select 1 from reports where enter::date = '2020-11-08' and employeeid = i) then
       return query select employeeid, lastname, firstname, department, position from employee where employeeid = i;        
    end if;
end loop;
```

Seems to me, it's not an ideal solution. Is there any better approach to achieve the same result?
Thanks.

Comment: If you have a new question, then ask a new question (possibly linking back to this one). Don't extend your existing one

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is pretty non effective. Probably it cannot be written badly :-). The reply @a_horse_with_no_name is absolutely correct, just for completeness I'll fix your plpgsql code.

```
DECLARE _e employee;
BEGIN
  FOR _e IN SELECT * FROM employee
  LOOP
    IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT * 
                    FROM reports r
                   WHERE r.enter::date = date '2020-11-08'
                     AND r.employeeid = _e.employeeid)
    THEN
      RETURN NEXT _e;
    END IF;
  END LOOP;
END;
```

When you write stored procedure (or any query based application), the important value is number of queries - low number is better (attention - there are exceptions - sometimes too much complex queries can be slower due their complexity). In your example there are `employees * 2 + 1` queries (with larger overhead of plpgsql - `RETURN QUERY` is more expensive than `RETURN NEXT`). Solution proposed by @a_horse_with_no_name is one query (without a overhead of plpgsql). Any my example has `employees + 1` queries (with lower overhead of plpgsql).

Your example is good example of one common SQL antipattern - "using ISAM style".

Comment: Thanks for the deep explanation. One more question: how about if I need results in the period of the time? For example From=`2020-11-0`, To=`2020-11-08`. And result `employeeid, lastname, firstname, department, position, misseddate`

Comment: @Ma'ruf - it is not a problem just you can use `BETWEEN` operator instead `=`. When the result of query has not same structure like your expected result, then you can use a custom composite type. Almost all is possible - plpgsql and SQL are mature languages. Please, start by plpgsql documentation reading - it has less 50 pages, and you will see all possibilities - https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql.html

Comment: how about misseddate column in the return table? Now I'm updating my question.

Comment: The identifiers in `RETURNS TABLE(...)` are `OUT` variables too. So you can fill these variables and use `RETURN NEXT` without arguments, or you can use composite value in `REURN NEXT` like `RETURN NEXT (r.employeeid, r. ..., _f_from_date)`.

Comment: so is that the correct way of looping through date ranges? ``_res = f_to - f_from;``
    ``for i in 0.._res``  _loop_  ``_from = f_from + i;``

Comment: @Ma'ruf - yes, it is possible

Answer (score 0):

You are right: more often than not, a loop is a bad way to do things in a relational database.

You can do this in plain SQL:

```
select e.employeeid, e.lastname, e.firstname, e.department, e.position 
from employee e
where not exists (select *
                  from reports r
                  where r.enter::date = date '2020-11-08'
                    and e.employeeid = r.employeeid);
```

This will return all employees for which no row exists in the `reports` table on 2020-11-08